# With newer version of Java some of my applications shortcuts are being overridden by MacOS shortcuts

Tags: java, macos, swing, java-11

My application used Java 8 and on MacOS many actions have shortcuts defined that work fine, such as this one defined to use COMMAND-1

```
public final class AutoCorrectAction
    extends CorrecterAction
{
    private static final String ACTION_NAME = "autocorrect";
    

    public AutoCorrectAction(final int paneIndex)
    {
        super(ACTION_NAME, TextLabel.MENU_AUTOCORRECT.getMsg(), paneIndex);
        if (paneIndex == TagDisplayer.INDEX_NONE)
        {
            putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY,(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1,
                                          Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask())));

        }
     
        this.putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, JaikozIcon.LOCAL_AUTOCORRECT.getIconSmall());
        this.putValue(JaikozAction.LARGE_ICON, JaikozIcon.LOCAL_AUTOCORRECT.getIconLarge());
        this.putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION,TextLabel.MENU_AUTOCORRECTTOOLTIP.getMsg());

    }

    public final void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
    {
        start.logger.entering(this.getClass().getName(), JaikozLogFormatter.ACTION_PERFORMED);      
        this.performTask(new AutoCorrecter(start, isSelectedOnly(e), isUseRowSelection));
        start.logger.exiting(this.getClass().getName(), JaikozLogFormatter.ACTION_PERFORMED);
    }
}
```

My latest version of software now uses Java 11, and now when i press COMMAND-1 it minimizes the windows and shows in Finder, a google search determined this is a standard mac shortcut - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

> Command-1: View the items in the Finder window as icons.

**So my question is what is the correct mac behaviour, should my shortcut in my application override the  MacOS shortcut or not, i.e is this a bug introduced in Java 11 or was the previous behaviour buggy and now fixed.**

Confusingly, I have another action defined in the same way that uses **Command-2**, this is also a standard MacOS  shortcut

> Command-2: View the items in a Finder window as a list.

```
public final class CreateAcousticIdAction
    extends CorrecterAction
{
    private static final String ACTION_NAME = "createmusicipacousticid";


    public CreateAcousticIdAction(final int paneIndex)
    {
        super(CreateAcousticIdAction.ACTION_NAME, TextLabel.MENU_CREATE_MUSICIP_ACOUSTIC_ID.getMsg(), paneIndex);
        this.putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, JaikozIcon.CREATE_MUSICIP_PUID.getIconSmall());
        this.putValue(JaikozAction.LARGE_ICON, JaikozIcon.CREATE_MUSICIP_PUID.getIconLarge());

        this.putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, TextLabel.MENU_CREATE_MUSICIP_ACOUSTIC_IDTOOLTIP.getMsg());
        putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY,(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2,
                                          Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask())));
    }

    public final void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
    {
        this.performTask(new CreateAcoustId(start,  isSelectedOnly(e), isUseRowSelection), JaikozThreadGroup.THREAD_CREATE_ACOUSTICID);
    }
}
```

yet my shortcut continues to work and is not overridden by MacOS shortcuts !

**Update**
I have created movie as requested - http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/scratch/cmd1issue.mov

What I now notice is that when I press Cmd-1 it minimizes the window, but its run autocorrect as well so it does both things.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example? For me Command+1 doesn't do anything on osx, firefox uses it to select which tab is being displayed though.

Comment: As matt commented, please make a tiny minimal example app showing at least 2 or three of your overridden shortcuts.

Comment: The info is there, I have given yo the code and a shortcut that works and one that doesn't.

Comment: What code is there? You're creating a shortcut using 'putValue' which is not provided. You also have an 'if' statement, which could very well mean your accelerator isn't added at all. So somebody could make an example where command+1 works, but it is not the behavior you see.

Comment: ok I will do this tomorrow, I was hoping somebody would be awar eof some bug in Java 9, 10 or 11 since the problem did not occur with Java 8

Comment: @matt putValue comes from AbstractAction, CorrecterAction subclasses AbstractAction the accelerator is added because as I explained already it works fine with java 8

Comment: I have no problem using CMD + 1 to activate a button, so I cannot reproduce what you're seeing. Using jdk 11 or 14 with os x.

Comment: Given @matt's observation about no issue with jdk11 or 14, and your original that cmd-1 "minimizes the windows and shows in Finder", are you able to post a video of this behaviour? If so, please be sure to capture the top left area of the screen in the video as well, from the Apple icon through the menus.

Comment: @Glenn i have creatd a video, but doesnt seem you can add video to StackOverflow direcrtly ?

Comment: @Glenn, uploaded to server and added link instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Found the issue, I didnt realize that I was also using Command-1 for maxmizing windows within the application as well, removing this shortcut resolved the issue

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve this, Paul! I think you're hitting cmd-1 at about the 10-second mark. Notice there's a quick flash of the Window menu title at that point. That indicates the menu under which the shortcut is being selected. (For example, if you hit cmd-P to print, the File menu will flash briefly.) So...if I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like "maximizing windows" -- tied to cmd-1 -- was shown under the Window menu.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is what is the correct mac behaviour, should my
> shortcut in my application override the MacOS shortcut or not, i.e is
> this a bug introduced in Java 11 or was the previous behaviour buggy
> and now fixed.

Not that it helps, but...I think the question itself is flawed, at least for this issue.

Your google search was correct that command-1 in Finder lists the contents of a window as icons.  But the key there is *in Finder*.  That behaviour does not affect other applications; it's specific to Finder.  Said differently, it's a Finder shortcut, not a macOS shortcut.

There *are* some system-wide ("macOS") shortcuts, like for capturing the image of a screen (command-shift-3 et al), or for bringing up Spotlight (command-space). But command-1 is not one of those, nor is command-2.

So your original question, of which shortcut (app or OS) should override the other, is moot for command-1 and command-2.

A quick search did not reveal Mac-specific release notes for JDK11 LTR, but I suspect the issue is indeed part of some change in JDK9, 10, or 11.  I do not know how to work around that, but if you have Mac-specific release notes, they may provide a hint.

To answer the original question in general -- not related to this specific issue -- if memory serves, the macOS shortcut takes precedence...but there's also a way around that. Apple > System Preferences... > Keyboard > Shortcuts lets you change an existing system-wide shortcut (though generally I would advise against that), or -- better yet -- add one that you think an app *should* have.

The catches with that last are (1) it has to be an executable app (so not a .jar), and (2) it must be a standard GUI app where the desired action exists as a menu item, not a UNIX CLI executable.

Comment: awarded bounty as best answer before time runs out, I havent solved yet will have to come back to this next week.

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I don't have much experience with MacOS or creating OS macros from java that interact with non-third party apps (generally against the goal of java which is meant to be platform independent).

Answer: The macro hierarchy would generally be determined by the OS and be affected by the java compiler/jvm implementation. Ideally a third party and likely untrusted java program (which is generally the case for developers) should be last in priority to receive the key macro thus any programs that use macros should avoid any likely pre-existing macros or ensure that they have a greater focus than the OS/other programs to ensure they receive all input before them.

Theoretical Implementation: Two main ways I can think of to achieve this are to create a configure file/program to allow the user to define what key-macro to access the program (which makes it always possible to avoid conflicts regardless of OS) or to have a wake up macro that is unlikely to be by other programs (mac equiv of ctr-shift-k) which causes a program to gain focus over the OS and then the program can call as many key macros as it wants.

Note: regarding why it happened, I would guess the java code previously required extra privileges to run (which makes it more dangerous if an exploit is found) thus as a side effect it was given higher priority by the OS in other aspects too. Thus when the privilege level dropped after it was fixed (with all the other security features in java 11) its position in the key-macro hierarchy would have dropped too.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Interested in hearing if you are able to pin it down, particularly given that cmd-1 and cmd-2 appear to be handled differently. One long-shot to check: you said cmd-1 in the app changes to Finder and shows the app there. I suspect you double-clicked in the Finder to launch it in the beginning (which caused it to become highlighted), and now it's just "hiding" the app, same as appname > Hide appname. Does that cmd-1 behaviour happen with any other app? (Hiding is usually via cmd-H, shown in the appname menu.)

Comment: @Glenn So it doesnt change to finder, it minimizes the window, added video